# Why my NULL check is always failing in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am developing a REST API with AWS Lambda, API Gateway, and Node.js.

Here is my code:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');

const prop = PropertiesReader('properties.properties');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : prop.get('server.host'),
  user     : prop.get("server.username"),
  password : prop.get("server.password"),
  port     : prop.get("server.port"),
  database : prop.get("server.dbname")
});


exports.getMilestoneStatusByID = (event, context, callback) => {

  const { id } = event.queryStringParameters;

  if(id==null)
  {
    var response = {
      "statusCode": 404,
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      "body": JSON.stringify("Missing Parameters"),
      "isBase64Encoded": false
    };
    callback(null, response)

    
  }
  else{
    console.log("id", id);

    // allows for using callbacks as finish/error-handlers
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    const sql = "select * from milestone_status where idmilestone_status = ?";
    con.execute(sql, [id], function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
  
      var response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": JSON.stringify(result),
        "isBase64Encoded": false
      };
      callback(null, response)
    });
  }
  
};
```

In my code I am accepting a parameter called `id`, then get data from the database and return back as the response. If the `id` is not provided, i am sending an error response.

But, in any case the `id` is null or no parameter provided, then the user gets the standard AWS error output, `"message": "Internal server error"`. In console, th But what I need is to pass 404 status code, with the message `Missing Parameters`.
e below error get printed.

```
Lambda returned empty body!
Invalid lambda response received: Invalid API Gateway Response Keys: {'trace', 'errorMessage', 'errorType'} in {'errorType': 'TypeError', 'errorMessage': "Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'event.queryStringParameters' as it is null.", 'trace': ["TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'event.queryStringParameters' as it is null.", '    at Runtime.exports.getMilestoneStatusByID [as handler] (/var/task/source/milestone-status/milestonestatus-getbyid.js:17:11)', '    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)']}
```

How can I implement `null` check and send the error that I am looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that `event.queryStringParameters` is `undefined`, not the `.id` in it. You can extend your check to also check for `event.queryStringParameters`, although you should check the documentation if that's even normal:

```js
exports.getMilestoneStatusByID = (event, context, callback) => {

    const params = event.queryStringParameters;

    if (!params || params.id == null) {
        var response = {
            "statusCode": 404,
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            "body": JSON.stringify("Missing Parameters"),
            "isBase64Encoded": false
        };
        callback(null, response)
    } else {
        const { id } = params;
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: wow, Okay. This fixed the issue. Can you also tell me how I can send the error like a `JSON`, for an example `{"error":"Missing Parameters"}` ? Right now it is just `Missing parammeters`

Comment: You could simply replace `JSON.stringify("Missing Parameters")` with `JSON.stringify({ error= "Missing Parameters" })`

Comment: It isn't. I made a typo and that `=` is supposed to be a `:` instead. But you get the idea of stringifying an object instead of just a string.